# Asterisk + FreePBX не звонит

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

Asterisk + FreePBX не звонит

Вроде бы всё настроено правильно

Не могу понять, в чем проблема

```
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  0 [ 18]: SIP/2.0 200 Got it
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  1 [ 91]: Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.102:5160;received=46.150.92.66;branch=z9hG4bK25a74a51;rport=5160
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  2 [ 62]: From: "Unknown" <sip:136963@192.168.0.102:5160>;tag=as6f01c38f
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  3 [ 67]: To: <sip:sip.comtube.com>;tag=9766e6cd6366e4381d550735b7db114a.75d7
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  4 [ 60]: Call-ID: 56776af21644144e0a2f99216f9566dd@192.168.0.102:5160
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  5 [ 17]: CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  6 [ 25]: Server: Comtube SIP Proxy
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9899 parse_request:  Header  7 [ 17]: Content-Length: 0
--- (8 headers 0 lines) ---
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:9425 __find_call: = Looking for  Call ID: 56776af21644144e0a2f99216f9566dd@192.168.0.102:5160 (Checking To) --From tag as6f01c38f --To-tag 9766e6cd6366e4381d550735b7db114a.75d7
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:4523 __sip_ack: ** SIP TIMER: Cancelling retransmit of packet (reply received) Retransid #2
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:4534 __sip_ack: Stopping retransmission on '56776af21644144e0a2f99216f9566dd@192.168.0.102:5160' of Request 102: Match Found
[2018-11-30 01:21:08] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:6586 sip_pvt_dtor: Destroying SIP dialog 56776af21644144e0a2f99216f9566dd@192.168.0.102:5160
Really destroying SIP dialog '56776af21644144e0a2f99216f9566dd@192.168.0.102:5160' Method: OPTIONS
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[25420]: manager.c:6474 process_message: Running action 'Login'
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[25420]: manager.c:6474 process_message: Running action 'Originate'
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[25420]: chan_sip.c:30477 sip_request_call: Asked to create a SIP channel with formats: (slin)
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[25420]: chan_sip.c:9012 __sip_alloc: Allocating new SIP dialog for 4bedd85c71dd12df5a5f9d0254ae3280@[fe80::16fd:14d0:8ec:c8b0]:5160 - INVITE (No RTP)
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[25420]: chan_sip.c:30597 sip_request_call: Cant create SIP call - target device not registered
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[25420]: manager.c:6474 process_message: Running action 'Logoff'
[2018-11-30 01:21:14] DEBUG[19350]: chan_sip.c:6586 sip_pvt_dtor: Destroying SIP dialog 4bedd85c71dd12df5a5f9d0254ae3280@[fe80::16fd:14d0:8ec:c8b0]:5160
[2018-11-30 01:21:21] DEBUG[19338]: res_pjsip_registrar.c:1235 check_expiration_thread: Woke up at 154353008
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял логи, он хочет звонить на устройство в соответствии с диалпланом и обнаруживает, что это устройство на нём не зарегистрировано.